# How to return back to a fragment in viewpager from an Activity's fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a `viewpager` with 2 fragments(A and B) in `MainActivity`. In the fragments in `viewpager`, I have a `recyclerView` for each fragment that contains a list of items. When I click on an item of a fragment `viewpager`, it displays a new `Activity` with a new fragment (C) on it. But when I press the back button on toolbar, it always went back to the `MainActivity` with fragment A of `viewpager`, even if I click on item of fragment B.

In `androidManifest.xml`, I added `"parentActivity: MainActivity"` to the new Activity. If I don't set that, the back button would not response.
I need help to go back to the correct fragment when I press back button.

I appreciate all answers.

Comment: Try to do it programmatically. Send some value to your C fragment and when you will click back button check the value and set necessary page in your view pager.

Comment: can you post an example code please, I dont know how to addtobackstack to a fragment of viewpager

Comment: Actually I am suggesting to send some value from fragment to another fragment and check the value for different cases (does fragment opened from A or B fragment)

Comment: I had same idea, but don't know how to implement it :((

Comment: Added code block to relevant keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy. Keep an index variable in your activity in which viewpager and fragments are loaded. When you switch to another activity, do it via this activities method and update that variable with the index of the current selected page/fragment in viewpager by

> getCurrentItem

This method will return the index which you can store then there are two options for you: If you know that your activity is going to be resumed from that activity only then you can write below method in onResume:

> setCurrentItem

Or else you can go for startActivityForResult and achieve the same. Let me know if any queries.

Comment: Can you tell me where I put getCurrentItem please? Will it regconize the fragment I clicked without listener? In MainActivity, I overrided onResume() then mPager=setCurrentItem(mPagePosition);

Comment: setCurrentItem and getCurrentItem are methods of Viewpager. I would suggest startActivityForResult but do what suits you. You should write as index = mPager.getCurrentItem and mPager.setCurrentItem(index). Write getCurrentItem before switching in the method where you call startActivity or startActivityForResult and setCurrentItem in onResume or onActivityResult

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now, but I have a last question because I created intent and called startActivity() in fragment, so in MainActivity I create public static int mPageposition, public static Viewpager mPager= null. By that I could call getcurrentItem() in fragment and assign mPageposition, because my fragment outside MainAc. Is that ok if I make them 2 public static ?

Comment: Create a method in mainActivity, e.g., openSecondActivity(), call that method from your fragment. You don't need to make those variables static. If it helped, please upvote.

Comment: I created a method in mainActivity public int setPagePosition(){ return mPager.getCurrentItem;} then I called it in my fragment, but it caused errors "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.getCurrentItem()' on a null object reference"

Comment: That must be because you would be initialising your viewpager after that getCurrentIem is called. Either way, this is also good way.

Comment: I just fix my setPagePosition(int position) {this.mPagePosition=position), then in fragment I passed 1 or 0 depends on which fragment I called, I run debugger , and I see mPagePosition was assigned to 1 as I want, but onResume() mPagePosition still 0, I created int mPageposition on top of MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

First of all let assume you pressed something to open C fragment from B fragment. Here you need to pass some value to inform that C was opened from B fragment.

**Send data from fragment to activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                    TargetActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("B", message);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Here value "B" means that activity with fragment C is opened by fragment B. For A fragment you need to change it to "A" or whatever you want.

**Receive data in activity and send it back if Back button pressed**

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.class, FirstActivity.class)
                intent.putString(message)
            }
        });
```

**Receive data in FirstActivity and set necessary page**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
if(message == "B"){
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1) //1 is index of your second page 
}else {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0)
}
```

Try this code and let me know if something goes wrong

Comment: I coud pass the intent to newActivity, in the newActivity, I overrided onBackPress() and I created intent pass the intent with "B" to MainActivity. But I got error here in MainActivity. I overrided onResume() to get the intent, but it's error because the intent is null . I don't know why onResume() runs before I press back button in the newActivity.

Comment: @Long Can you show what you have done by posting the code

Answer (score 0):

First, for going to "NewActivity" just start the activity using intent and **not finish the "MainActivity"**.

And For coming back to "MainActivity", just finish the "NewActivity"... hopefully, this will work!